# How do I prevent long emails from becoming attachments?

Tags: linux, bash, email, email-attachments

When a build finishes, the bash script calls:

```
nail -s "Build completed" $towhom < buildreport
```

When the *buildreport* is over 2,000 characters long, it arrives as an attachment.

Where can one set the threshold for the size of the body becoming an attachment?

Comment: Most linux variants of the mail program do not convert the content of a message into an attachment - it simply arrives as is (I have several multi-kilobyte messages constructed in this manner).

Is it possible that the buildreport file itself is a mime message?

Comment: The buildreport is simply the status of the build, with the "error" statements from the builds "grep'd". So when the build is full of errors, this output can get long.

Usually it arrives as plain text - since it's a few lines long.

Comment: You've been way to vague as to what you're using - 'mail' could be any of a multitude of applications. I know that mutt can auto-convert/encode when sending if there are any 8-bit characters in the message - are there any 8-bit characters in the message i.e. characters over 127?

Comment: @Petesh The example uses `nail`, with an `n`. That's a very specific mailer. I think you're on the right track with character sensitivity, but not necessarily 8-bit values. The Google hits I get say that `nail` also considers characters like Backspace or Carriage Return in the input to be illegal. This concurs with a quick skim of the [program source](http://nail.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nail/nail/mime.c) which flags characters below 0x20 other that aren't Newlines, Tabs or FormFeeds. So I think the next step is for Danny to look for 8-bit or control characters in these attachments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment from ottomeister, There are a lot of reasons why the mail would be autoconverted to an attachment by `nail`

- Individual lines are too long (>950 characters)
- There are control characters in the message

If the message is UTF-8, then it seems as though it gets properly parsed (but this is only based on code from on-line, which may not be what you're using)

You could probably run the content of the file through a filter - e.g. to remove all non-ascii characters:

```
tr -cd '\11\12\15\40-\176' <buildreport | nail -s "Build completed" $towhom
```

... but that will clobber all UTF-8 characters

If you want to get the log input to wrap at 1 number of characters, then you can use a perl one-liner like:

```
perl -e 'use Text::Wrap; print wrap("", "  ", <STDIN>);' < buildreport | nail -s "Build completed" $towhom
```

Comment: I think the real issue may be "Individual lines are too long (>950 characters)". 

I've implemented your patch and "time will tell".

Thanks.

Comment: I added a perl one-liner to wrap text as well

Comment: The solution that seems to work best - after months of trail & error is this ==> tr -d '\11\15\176' <buildreport | nail -s "Build completed" $towhom" <==. BTW the \12 creates a one-liner email which is very hard to read.

Comment: Just for the record: We're added a few over the past few months, and now we have: tr -d 'œ“”â€™’‘\11\15\176\200\230'